# Jekyll serve -w Issue

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I am using the jekyll with git-hub-pages on Win7, however no matter what I do the

```
jekyll serve --watch or
jekyll serve -w
```

won't start the server (the jekyll serve is working fine).
the produced error has something to do with

```
custom_require.rb:36 - cannot load such a file --wdm
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the error message, `wdm` is not found.

First, update your gems

```
gem update
```

Then, manually install `wdm`

```
gem install wdm
```

Comment: Actually I already found the answer ... same with yours ... thanks